# Bootstrap validation with JavaScript

Tags: ajax, forms, validation

I have bootstrap form, but I use Ajax on click submit button and the function is performed regardless of the input data. How to check validation with javascript and then do ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

Add a javascript function to your submit button click event that will validate and call ajax if validated:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input id="btn_submit" type="button" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function validate() {
    return true;
}
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#btn_submit').on('click', function() {
        if (validate()) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'myPhp.php',
                data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: window.validate is not a function

Comment: before you give details of how you tried we can only guess how to have you improve your solution. I gave a general framework of javascript form validation before ajax-submitting above...